# how do I prevent left join for owned properties in entity framework core 3.1?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    // # Address
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string? Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string? Region { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    private Address() {}
}
```

EntityConfiguration

```
public class EmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Address);
    }
}
```

Generated SQL

```
SELECT t."Id", t."BsonId", t."Code", t."CompanyId", t."Created", t."DateOfBirth", t."FullName", t."Gender", t."LastModified", t."MaritalStatus", t."Status", t1."Id", t1."Address_Address1", t1."Address_Address2", t1."Address_City", t1."Address_PostCode", t1."Address_Region"
  FROM (
      SELECT e."Id", e."BsonId", e."Code", e."CompanyId", e."Created", e."DateOfBirth", e."FullName", e."Gender", e."LastModified", e."MaritalStatus", e."Status"
      FROM "I180814-04-edm"."Employees" AS e
      ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
      LIMIT @__p_1 OFFSET @__p_0
  ) AS t
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT e0."Id", e0."Address_Address1", e0."Address_Address2", e0."Address_City", e0."Address_PostCode", e0."Address_Region", e1."Id" AS "Id0"
      FROM "I180814-04-edm"."Employees" AS e0
      INNER JOIN "I180814-04-edm"."Employees" AS e1 ON e0."Id" = e1."Id"
      WHERE (e0."Address_Region" IS NOT NULL) OR ((e0."Address_PostCode" IS NOT NULL) OR ((e0."Address_City" IS NOT NULL) OR ((e0."Address_Address2" IS NOT NULL) OR (e0."Address_Address1" IS NOT NULL))))
  ) AS t0 ON t."Id" = t0."Id"
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT e2."Id", e2."Address_Address1", e2."Address_Address2", e2."Address_City", e2."Address_PostCode", e2."Address_Region", e3."Id" AS "Id0"
      FROM "I180814-04-edm"."Employees" AS e2
      INNER JOIN "I180814-04-edm"."Employees" AS e3 ON e2."Id" = e3."Id"
      WHERE (e2."Address_Region" IS NOT NULL) OR ((e2."Address_PostCode" IS NOT NULL) OR ((e2."Address_City" IS NOT NULL) OR ((e2."Address_Address2" IS NOT NULL) OR (e2."Address_Address1" IS NOT NULL))))
  ) AS t1 ON t."Id" = t1."Id"
```

Did I miss something? I searched all over but I could not find anyway to modify the generated SQL for OwnedProperties in Ef core. Is there a way to setup the relationships so that ef core projects the properties as if it was a single model rather than detecting it as a relationship and generating a left join.

Comment: Yes, there are even two ways, but you won't like them. Either go back to the latest EF Core 2.2, or wait for EF Core 5.0 to get this bug **eventually** fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are nothings wrongs with generated SQL statement (left join).

You can use right predicate to be sure `address` is not null like inner join without any performance impact:

```
var result = await dbcontext.Employee.Include(x => x.Include(y => y.Address)).Where(p => p.Address != null).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This is a very common approach.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue in Entity Framework Core 3.1.  It has been fixed in Entity Framework 5.0.  The bug ticket has some useful discussions about performance and workarounds, if you aren't able to upgrade.  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18299